# Bootstrap tabs don't deactivate

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I'm using the tabs component from Bootstrap, and it seems to work fine, but when I go to a tab then leave it, the tab keeps the *active* class. So they won't work when I've gone through all of them. This is the code I have (I'm using Django)

```
<ul id="question-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" data-tabs="question-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#latest" data-toggle="tab">Latest</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#unans" data-toggle="tab">Unanswered <span class="badge">{{ total_noans }}</span></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#reward" data-toggle="tab">Most Rewarding <span class="badge">{{ reward | length }}</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I haven't found the problem, I tried using the JS snippet Bootstrap provides...

```
$('#question-tabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

... but it didn't work. It may be a silly thing but I couldn't figure out. I appreciate any help.

If you want a live example of what I'm saying, go to https://seoq.swapps.io/qa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was a silly thing. In the base template the Bootstrap.js file that was being called was the one for version 4. Now it works. I'm sorry and thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the code like this in your page specific (project.js) script. I hope this will resolve the issue:

```
$(function(){
  $('#question-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  });
});
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: That's not the problem. This won't solve it, the tabs still don't deactivate

Comment: @AndrewL. In console it shows "TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function" . see this image [here](http://prnt.sc/cej3jh)

Comment: I know, that means that `$(...).tab` is not defined. That's probably because the script isn't there. With your modification, it still doesn't work.

Comment: All the code from Bootstrap is in there, I also tried adding it from CDN and it didn't work.